# Replacing character in string which does not match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an `input` text box with a max length of 20. In this text box I only want to allow the following characters `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, a `whitespace`, an underscore `_`, a dash `-`, a forward slash `/`, and a back slash `\`.

So I have come up with the following function.

```js
$("#se_del").keyup(function (e) {
    const regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9 _\/\-\\]+/g;
    if (regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(regex, '');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="se_del" />
```

But it does not seem to replace the value in the textbox with an empty string if it doesn't match it. Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If it does not match, how can the text be replaced? Only what is matched is replaced. Could you clarify please?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry for confusion. If for example I enter `?` or `#` this character should be replaced with empty string

Comment: It is removed, but it is shown before it is removed. It is because you are using `keyup` event.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew can you provide an exmaple please if possible

Comment: I do not understand what the issue is, but there is one who might, see an answer below.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The non matching char is being displayed but is not being remove using `.replace(regex, '');`

Comment: See your code in the snippet in the answer below. It behaves exactly the same. `?` or `#` are removed. I turned your code into a snippet, see?

Comment: Why did you accept the answer that is exactly like yours? So, there was no issue, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138956/discussion-between-code-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of , use `\s` for space in regex.  will kill your regex

```js
$("#se_del").on('keyup',function (e) {
    const regex = /[^a-zA-Z0-9\s_\/\-\\]+/g;
    if (regex.test(this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace(regex, '');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="se_del" />
```

Comment: What do you mean by "kill"? There is not much difference here if OP uses `\s` or a space.

Comment: I used it literally. I mean it will not function as expected.

Comment: OP regex already removed the `#` and `?`. I really have no clue why this answer is accepted. I am sure OP had a typo somewhere in the code.